# Как сделать спуск страницы с помощью кнопки?

Tags: javascript, html

Как сделать чтобы при нажатии на кнопку спускалось вниз там где начинается определенный раздел(название кнопки=название раздела)?

Comment: Это называется якорь. В интернете куча примеров

Comment: @Yuri спасибо, я просто названия не знал